# How to solve problem with POST request error from angular 5 to java rest services call?

Tags: java, angular, rest, http-post, resteasy

I received the following error from java application running on tomcat when
trying to submit POST request from angular 5 application to a java application
using restful services:

> 23:26:22,191 ERROR [BaseXMLFilter] Exception in the filter chain
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:326)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:198)
>       at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:63)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
>       at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>       at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>       at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;**
>       at javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.computeExceptionMessage(WebApplicationException.java:211)
>       at javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.(WebApplicationException.java:185)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.readFrom(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:89)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:46)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.ReaderUtility.doRead(ReaderUtility.java:106)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.ReaderUtility.doRead(ReaderUtility.java:93)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:120)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:93)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:116)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:211)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:176)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:166)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:359)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:336)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:103)
>       at org.jboss.seam.resteasy.ResteasyResourceAdapter$1.process(ResteasyResourceAdapter.java:145)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.ContextualHttpServletRequest.run(ContextualHttpServletRequest.java:53)
>       at org.jboss.seam.resteasy.ResteasyResourceAdapter.getResource(ResteasyResourceAdapter.java:121)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet.service(SeamResourceServlet.java:80)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       ... 44 more
>   Sep 26, 2018 11:26:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Seam Resource Servlet] in context with path [/jboss-seam-jpa] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] **with root cause
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;**
>       at javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.computeExceptionMessage(WebApplicationException.java:211)
>       at javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.(WebApplicationException.java:185)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.readFrom(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:89)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:46)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.ReaderUtility.doRead(ReaderUtility.java:106)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.ReaderUtility.doRead(ReaderUtility.java:93)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:120)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:93)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:116)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:211)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:176)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:166)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:359)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:336)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:103)
>       at org.jboss.seam.resteasy.ResteasyResourceAdapter$1.process(ResteasyResourceAdapter.java:145)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.ContextualHttpServletRequest.run(ContextualHttpServletRequest.java:53)
>       at org.jboss.seam.resteasy.ResteasyResourceAdapter.getResource(ResteasyResourceAdapter.java:121)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet.service(SeamResourceServlet.java:80)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:198)
>       at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:63)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
>       at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>       at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>       at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>       at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Angular 5 application code:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/jboss-seam-jpa/seam/resource/rest';

 addLocation(locationTemp: Location): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Location`, JSON.stringify(locationTemp), httpOptions);
}
```

Java code:

```
@POST
@Path("Location")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response addLocation(Location location) {
        myDao.addLocation(location);
        return Response.ok().entity("Location added successfully").build();
}
```

The full jars lib from the java application:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You using some incompatible versions of the JAX-RS API. I highly suggest you learn to use Maven. I will not take long to learn and it will save you much headache when dealing with dependency management. The figure out what implementation you want to use. Your dependencies are all over the place. You have both Jersey jars and RESTEasy jars. You need to decide on one and remove all remnants of the other.

Comment: Incompatible version make sense. I'm using seam and it comes with RESTEasy so I guess I'll have to keep it. But, when I remove the Jersey jars, tomcat is not even starting.

Comment: I didn't know you were using Jersey. You tagged your question with resteasy.

Comment: jaxrs-ri is a complete implementation. it comes with all the jersey jars packaged into one jar, including the JAX-RS apis. jaxrs-api has all the JAX-RS apis, and so does javax.ws.rs-api. My suggestion would be to just try to remove that latter two and see what happens.

Comment: I'm new to REstful services, I'm not even sure where I'm using Jersey and why I'm getting error on startup when removing the jars. I added the error to the original question (error from tomcat when removing these jars).

Comment: Dont remove the jersey jars. Read my last comment. Just remove those two

Comment: Removing both javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1 and jaxrs-api-2.0.1.ga was a safe move as I didn't get change or problem when loading the application but I'm still getting the same error when POST: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;

Comment: From the research I've done it seems you would get this error when you have both JAX-RS 1.x and 2.x classes, but I don't see anywhere you have an 1.x. So I'm not sure.

Comment: I've added the full jars lib list to the original question.

Comment: Only thing I can see that it might be is resteasy-jaxrs.

Comment: I _strongly_ urge you to take a day to learn Maven. It will make you life a lot easier. When you're done, then build your app from scratch using Maven. You're app right now is a pain to look at.

Comment: removing resteasy-jaxrs failed tomcat to start: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/specimpl/UriInfoImpl

Answer (score -1):

from the stacktrace it looks like you are doing the request from a different host and port from your browser and Tomcat does not like that. I see two possible solutions, one is to configure the Tomcat [CORS](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) filter to accept request from all host and ports or just for the one you want, although this may not be the solution you'll want to have on production.

If you are working with Angular CLI there is a way to configure a [proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) for your web app, in this case the Tomcat Application Server.

Cheers.

Comment: _"from the stacktrace it looks like you are doing the request from a different host and port from your browser and Tomcat does not like that"_ - How do you figure? I see an AbstractMethodError.